# How do I get rid of slash after URL in HTML website?

Tags: html, web-config

I have this HTML website that I need to get rid of the slash after the URL. Here is my website structure if it helps:

```
--ROOT
  --about
    --index.html
  --index.html
  --web.config
```

When I open the page in Chrome and visit the "about" page, it adds a slash after "about". (I don't type in "index.html", it just adds one (I know why it does that, I just want to fix it))

URL for Home Page: "ROOT"
URL for About Page: "ROOT/about/"

I tried using some other Stack Overflow posts, they didn't work at all. Instead, the slash was still there. I even tried getting rid of the slash on the a tag that takes you there.

Comment: A slash after `about` would be technically correct. `about` in your case is a directory and a slash indicates that. A browser would then search for an index page which you provide. iow, there is no problem but you are asking how to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Having a slash at the end of the URL does not seem like such a big issue but your server is most likely sending back a 301, redirecting you to the path with a "/" appended. The easiest/hacky way of solving this is just to modify it with JavaScript on the browser with the following code:

```js
window.history.pushState('', '', location.pathname.slice(0,-1));
```

The code uses the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) and fetches the current path and removes the last character from it giving the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, but where do I put it?

EDIT: I put it in the main JavaScript file, I realized

Comment: Also edit, it DID send back a 301